# C# Остановить ffmpeg

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

если я использую консольный ffmpeg

```
Process.Start("ffmpeg", "-f gdigrab -framerate 10 -i desktop out.mp4")
```

для записи видело экрана

то как мне остановить процесс?

Answer (score 3):

Создать процесс на основе `ProcessStartInfo` с `RedirectStandardInput` и записать в поток символ `q` в тот момент, когда надо будет остановить запись.

Answer (score 0):

```
var p = Process.Start(...);
...
p.Kill();
```

<s>Обращаю внимание, что таким образом убивается запущенный процесс, т. е. конвертирование не будет завершено. Если надо, чтобы конвертирование завершилось, то с процессом вообще ничего не надо делать.</s> В случае записи экрана это, вероятно, неактуально.

---

```
Process.Start("ffmpeg", "ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 10 -i desktop out.mp4")
//                       ^^^^^^ а это тут зачем?
```

Comment: поправил. но ответ явно не по теме. прибить консоль это одно, а остановить запись это другое

Comment: @des1roer, это не консоль, а сам ffmpeg. Хочешь сказать, что запись при вызове Kill не прекращается? Что-то сомневаюсь. Кстати, вместо Kill можно попробовать CloseMainWindow.